# gnu make - how to iterate through a list with shell? (TeXLive needed)

Tags: loops, makefile

I want to get bibliographical information from CTAN using `ctanbib`.

But instead of writing and executing

```
ctanbib datatool >> MyPackage-ctan.bib
ctanbib biblatex >> MyPackage-ctan.bib
ctanbib archaeologie >> MyPackage-ctan.bib
```

(and many more)

I thought of making a `make file` which would do the job.
But it will not get the information which must be due to the `shell` command.

```
NAME  = MyPackage
PKG   := datatool biblatex archaeologie
CTAN  := $(shell ctanbib $$pkg >> $(NAME)-ctan.bib)

getCTAN:
    for pkg in $(PKG);\
    do                \
     $(CTAN);         \
    done
```

Comment: For this use case, don't use make (its overcomplication). Write simple shell script instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `$(shell...)` make macro while you do not want shell evaluation. Your `CTAN` variable is set to the result of the evaluation by the shell of:

```
ctanbib $pkg >> MyPackage-ctan.bib
```

When I write "*the result*" I mean what this command echoes on the standard output. As there is probably no `pkg` shell variable set for the shell that performs this evaluation, this is probably the same as what the evaluation by the shell of:

```
ctanbib >> MyPackage-ctan.bib
```

sends to the standard output. And because you redirect the standard output to a file, this is the empty string. So, your `CTAN` variable is assigned the empty string.

Try:

```
CTAN := ctanbib $$pkg >> $(NAME)-ctan.bib
```

instead. The right hand side of the assignment will be expanded by make when assigning make variable `CTAN`. As a result the `CTAN` make variable will be assigned:

```
ctanbib $pkg >> MyPackage-ctan.bib
```

which is what you want in your recipe after make expands `$(CTAN)`. Example with the `ctanlib` command wrapped in `echo`:

```
$ cat Makefile
NAME  = MyPackage
PKG   := datatool biblatex archaeologie
CTAN  := echo "ctanbib $$pkg >> $(NAME)-ctan.bib"

.PHONY: getCTAN

getCTAN:
    rm -f $(NAME)-ctan.bib
    for pkg in $(PKG);\
    do                \
        $(CTAN);      \
    done
$ make
for pkg in datatool biblatex archaeologie;\
do                \
    echo "ctanbib $pkg >> MyPackage-ctan.bib";      \
done
ctanbib datatool >> MyPackage-ctan.bib
ctanbib biblatex >> MyPackage-ctan.bib
ctanbib archaeologie >> MyPackage-ctan.bib
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I still get `make: *** [getCTAN] Error 2`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Maybe some important information is missing. Did you try to wrap your `ctanlib` command in `echo` for debugging (see my edited answer for an example)? If yes, did you try to execute these commands directly from the terminal (just to check that what you want is doable)?

Comment: sorry for bothering you with this. but I still cannot get it work. writing `ctanbib ... >> ...` in the terminal works as expected.  But with the full example above and calling `make` in the terminal I get `Makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Comment: I got it!!!!! While copying your example the tab got replaced by four spaces....  :( Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Note that `MyPackage-ctan.bib` will grow each time you execute make. It is also good idea to mark getCTAN as `.PHONY`. Just in case you will get an idea to create a file getCTAN, and that makefile will stop working.:-)

Comment: @Kuchara: fixed both issues (but not sure for the first one: I don't know what the OP wants about this ever growing file). Thanks for your suggestions.